# Bash script to execute user input of another script

Tags: bash

I am creating a script but I am stuck because I need it to stimulate user input for another script that is call. I am able to answer the first question by going:
echo "y" | othercommand.sh
But I need to stimulate the answers for the other two questions, how would I go about this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "stimulate"?

Comment: You talk about 3 questions, but I cannot understand a single one of them, can you please clarify?

Comment: so are you kind of trying to treat the script like a function that returns a value? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399734/input-from-within-shell-script) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213127/simulate-user-input-to-call-script-multiple-times-with-different-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to answer `y`, `y`, `n` to the three questions, you can use a [here-doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) as shown below:

```
othercommand.sh << END
y
y
n
END
```

Comment: Hi, I have a srcipt and from this script I am calling another another script. But this script requires user input from command line. How do i stimulate this user input from my initial script?

Comment: Hi @dogbone, that doesn't seem to work. It still just accepts the fist input and ignores the others?